# How to make BluetoothDeviceInfo.Connected false?

Tags: 32feet

How can I disconnect a Bluetooth device, so that its `BluetoothDeviceInfo.Connected` is false?

I tried using `SetServiceState(BluetoothService.SerialPort, false)` but it'll still be connected.

I don't want to use `BluetoothSecurity.RemoveDevice` because it'll take too long to uninstall and then reinstall the device.

Is it possible? Or is this only availiable at the device side?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. The problem is that the properties in `BluetoothDeviceInfo` are set upon discovery. Any changes that happen later aren't notified.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/32feet.NET/InTheHand.Net.Personal/BluetoothDeviceInfo

So, if you want the property to be changed, you have to disconnect, perform another discovery and use the new data.